# C, Processes, fork

Tags: c, fork

How can I alter the program so that the functions `function_delayed_1` and `function_delayed_2` were performed only once and concurrently:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     printf("message 1.\n");
     fork();
     function_delayed_1();
     function_delayed_2();
     printf("message 2.\n");
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What did you learn in class? What did you learn from the documentation that you read?

Comment: Please read `fork` manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the `man` page of fork, and google some examples of `fork();`,, your code should be like as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     pid_t pid; // process ID

     printf("message 1.\n");
     pid = fork();
     if (pid < 0) {
         perror("fork");
         return;
     }

     if (pid == 0) {
         function_delayed_1(); // child process
     }
     else {
         function_delayed_2(); // parent process
     }
     printf("message 2.\n");
 }
```

Comment: Error checking is missing for the call to `fork()`. `function_delayed_2()` will be executed in any case, even if `fork()` failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("message 1.\n"); // printed once by parent process
    if(fork())
        function_delayed_1(); // executed by parent process
    else
        function_delayed_2(); // executed by child process

    printf("message 2.\n"); // will be printed twice once by parent & once by child.
}
```